# connecting to DBF files through network using PHP

Tags: php, foxpro

We have an old software in our company that uses FoxPro I think.The database files are DBF and I'm trying to connect to the database and display an online report. If I copy DBF files on the local PC and run PHP on the PC, everything is fine and the connection string is:

```
Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source="C:\\Users\\Ro\\Desktop\\Root\
```

The problem is the actual software and database are on another PC. I'm looking for a solution to use the real database, not a local copy.

Comment: Can't you put the files on a network share?

Comment: So edit the connection string to point to the actual location of the files. What specific problem are you having doing so?

Comment: I tried mapping drive and use something like z:\root, also, tried \\10.0.0.4\root, but in both situations, I received this message:Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '<b>Source:</b> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro<br/><b>Description:</b> Invalid path or file name.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php:4 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php(4): com->Open('Provider=VFPOLE...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 4

Comment: There's absolutely no reason you shouldn't be able to do this with the OLE DB provider. Does the user that the PHP call is running under have permissions to access the network share?

Comment: Yes, it's admin user. the only thing that I'm not sure is should I add username and password of the other PC to connection string? I mapped the network drive and saved the credential. It works for command prompt and other apps, I assumed is the same with PHP.

Comment: Did you get an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, there is no easy way to make a connection like you want to a VFP database. The issue is that your web server is running on a system level process, and when you try to use the ODBC or OLE then they are making use of a VFP Runtime and it has no understanding of non-local resources. In order to connect to VFP, the web server needs to have the hard drive where VFP resides connected as a local resource.

To make VFP web enabled, I used ColdFusion to quickly create a SOAP endpoint that managed all the SQL to query and update VFP, then any app on the web could use it.

If you have a MS SQL server, you could probably put the VFP database on that hard drive, and then create a remote connection from SQL server into VFP. Then your web app can use a SQL connection.